# Iframe in sencha Touch

Tags: iframe, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, facebook-iframe

I need to use a facebook like button iframe in my Android App...if I use this code I see it on my PC Desktop but I don't see anything in Android.

Do you know why and if exist a method to display the like button in Android?
I'm Using Sencha Architect and Touch 2.3
Thank you

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width&amp;height=62&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;appId=780849738633803" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: how do you add it. Inside a container with setHtml or ...

Comment: it is as you say you. I create a container and after I set a HTML

Answer (score 0):

It is as you say you.

This is my code:

```
htmlStrBase1 = '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fopticaltrend12345%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=780849738633803" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
component.add({
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'fb-root',
        width: 50,
        height: 20,
        flex:1,
    listeners: {
        initialize : function (container) {
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            container.setHtml(htmlStrBase);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hmmm. If you use a container, then there are severeal divs inside the container. That way #fb-root.x-inner.x-innerHtml is where the real fb html part begins. Did you try a component instead of container. You should build a fb custom component.

Comment: Can you write me a little example please?

Comment: Take a look at yourProject.touch.src.Button.js inside the template part you can define a div or span ... and add your text or html. The updateConfigItem is called every time the configItem changes. This should give you great control over your fb like.